# Integration Test Assertion Best Practice

Tags: python, pytest, integration-testing

I recently implemented integration tests on my legacy app, i get confused whe do assertion in Integration Test.

in unit test we can easily mock object and its make sense to only have 1 assertion every test. but when it becomes Integration Test, I want to verify the multiple scenarios and need to check every step is correct.

**is it okay to do multiple assertions ? or is there some best practice to do this ?**

here is my test code :

```
   def test_new_requested_depth_purchase_create_transaction(
        self,
        requested_depth_purchase_request_1: DepthPurchaseRequestViewModel,
    ):
        """depth_purchase_created_job() should create new lead,transaction and depth transaction package"""

        self._depth_purchase_request_service.depth_purchase_created_job(
            requested_depth_purchase_request_1.original_id
        )

        crm_depth_purchase = self._depth_purchase_repo.get_by_original_id(
            requested_depth_purchase_request_1.original_id
        )
        assert crm_depth_purchase is not None

        lead = self._lead_repo.get_by_id(crm_depth_purchase.leads_id)

        assert lead is not None

        transaction = self._transaction_repo.get_by_lead_id(lead.id)

        assert transaction is not None

        transaction_packages = self._transaction_package_repo.get_all_by_transaction_id(
            transaction.id
        )

        assert len(transaction_packages) > 0
        assert all(
            [
                trx_package.type == ProductPackageConstants.ALACARTE
                and trx_package.status_id == 0
                for trx_package in transaction_packages
            ]
        )
```

Test Framework : Pytest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes or no, it depends. The name "integration test" is poorly defined, there are many overlapping meanings.
It is simpler to define the extremes : unit tests usually have only one assertion, while end-to-end tests have many. With that in mind, there is strong reason wheter to prefer having multiple asserts or only one.

Another way to answer the question is based on the code schema "Given-When-Then". I could reorganize your code like that :

```py
def test_new_requested_depth_purchase_create_transaction(
    self,
    requested_depth_purchase_request_1: DepthPurchaseRequestViewModel,
):
    """depth_purchase_created_job() should create new lead,transaction and depth transaction package"""
    # When
    self._depth_purchase_request_service.depth_purchase_created_job(
        requested_depth_purchase_request_1.original_id
    )

    # Then
    crm_depth_purchase = self._depth_purchase_repo.get_by_original_id(
        requested_depth_purchase_request_1.original_id
    )
    assert crm_depth_purchase is not None

    lead = self._lead_repo.get_by_id(crm_depth_purchase.leads_id)
    assert lead is not None

    transaction = self._transaction_repo.get_by_lead_id(lead.id)
    assert transaction is not None

    transaction_packages = self._transaction_package_repo.get_all_by_transaction_id(
        transaction.id
    )
    assert len(transaction_packages) > 0
    assert all(
        [
            trx_package.type == ProductPackageConstants.ALACARTE
            and trx_package.status_id == 0
            for trx_package in transaction_packages
        ]
    )
```

There is no "Given" because it is taken care of by the fixture `requested_depth_purchase_request_1`. If the model was not injected, it would have to be created, which result in something like :

```py
def test_new_requested_depth_purchase_create_transaction(self):
    # Given
    requested_depth_purchase_request_1 = some_way_to_construct_it().maybe_in_several_steps()
    
    # When
    ...
```

In **theory**, you should not have asserts in your Given and When (your testing code should work properly), only in the Then because that is what the test is meant to tests. But it could serve as sanity checks.

For me, what you do is fine. Do what suits you (or your team).

Comment: Given, When, Then, it sounds like BDD. if something fails is it will be a problem to spot the error?

Comment: @FarisDewantoro BDD is way more than this : you should write your acceptance tests in advance to any feature code, and they should be executable (cf Gherkin+Cucumber). Here we are just structuring the test to clearly outline what is its purpose (which is already present in docstring), which helps to verify that all asserts are relevant. What I mean is that if you have several things to check (`lead`, `transaction`, `packages`) then all belong to the Then, and it is fine to have multiple asserts. But you could split your test in three if you want, there is no clear better solution, it depends.

Comment: but if I split to 3, it will be dry right? since to verify the transaction I need to get lead, and so on

Comment: In this case I would say that it is better with all the related asserts together. But If there were 10 asserts, maybe it should be split. With the fixture, the split in 3 would be DRY in my opinion, no less than your current example.

Comment: One last question btw, what is the benefit by spliting the assertion?

Comment: Depending on how the code under test is structured, you may prefer to have one test (with many asserts) that fail, or only one of several tests (having only one assert). That's why I mentioned the two extremes : with end-to-end tests, you want your test to abort on the first failed assert because after that you can't tell the state of your application. While unit test are usually meant to test only one thing (one "unit"), so it should fail for only one reason. It depends on your testing strategy (which tests to write) and thus on your project specific needs.